# Fail subsequent gulp tasks if first task fails

Tags: gulp, jshint

I have my default task in my gulpfile.js that looks something like this:

```
gulp.task('default', [
    'jshint',
    ...
]);
```

What I'd like to do is have the rest of the tasks not execute if task `jshint` returns warnings. In other words, "fail fast."

Is this possible? It appears to me that the tasks under `default` are run async, out of order—not serial.

Comment: in case of `jshint` it returns only warnings, i think thats why gulp proceeds to continue other tasks. However, suppose in case of `gulp-less`, the build fails (although silently!) if less to css compilation is not successful. And yes, the tasks in gulp task dependencies run async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Use the `fail` reporter with jshint to make it throw errors instead of warnings.
- Make your other tasks depend on the `jshint` task so that `jshint` always runs first.

```
gulp.task('default', ['js']);

gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.js')
    .pipe(jshint(opts))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});

gulp.task('js', ['jshint'], function() {
  //somethin
});
```